# C++ Increasing pointers in other way around

Tags: c++, pointers

My question is simple, im looking through the subject for my midterm tomorrow morning and its almost 1 am, im staying up with redbulls after a long midterm week.

I did check other questions but they are more like 
`++*ip` or `*ip = *ip+1` kind of questions.

So here it goes, hopefully i can understand

What does

```
*(ip+1) = *ip;
```

means?

Comment: It is identical to `ip[1] = ip[0];`. (assuming `ip` a pointer).

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you! THANK YOU! My mind is exploding rn. It was actually way too obvious but my stupid brain couldnt see until you made it obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It assaign's a value of object pointed to by ip to the object after object pointed to by ip. It's better explained with an example:
Let's assume ip points to a first int in int array:

```
[4, 5, 10, -1]
```

Here ip would point to 4.

```
ip+1
```

means that we want to move this pointer one position to the right (this now points to 5)

```
*(ip+1) and *ip
```

is a pointer dereferencing. This means that we want to operate on an object's value rather than pointer itself. So be saying `*(ip+1) = *ip;` you want to assign a value pointed to by ip to an object pointed to by ip+1 (usually a next object in an array). After this our example array is going to look like this:

```
[4, 4, 10, -1]
```

Note that this requires that you have memory pointed to by ip+1 allocated. This also works with any class (no only ints)